# What does “sitter” refer to in babysitter?

Tags: word-usage, etymology

According to Etymonline the noun ***[babysitter](https://www.etymonline.com/word/babysitter)*** is from 1914:

> also baby-sitter, "person who looks after a child or children while the parents are away," ***1914, from baby (n.) + agent noun from sit (v.)***. Short form sitter is attested from 1937.

While the verb  ***[babysit](https://www.etymonline.com/word/babysit)***,  from babysitter, is from 1947.

Curiously, other sources such as [Wordwizard](http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?t=6435) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babysitting#Etymology)  for instance, suggest that:

> ***The term "baby sitter" first appeared in 1937***, while the verb form "baby-sit" was first recorded in 1947.
>
> Thus the verb was derived from the agent noun rather than the other way around, and represents ***a good example of back-formation.***

As for the terms ***sitter/sit*** there are two main assumptions:

> The use of the word "sit" to refer to a person tending to a child is recorded from 1800. ***The term may have originated from the action of the caretaker "sitting on" the baby in one room***, while the parents were entertaining or busy in another. ***It's also theorized that the term may come from hens "sitting" on their eggs,***   thus "caring for" their chicks.

I couldn’t find any etymological reference of ***[sit](https://www.etymonline.com/word/sit?ref=etymonline_crossreference)*** for  the two senses described above, but certainly , the idea of hens “brooding” on their eggs conveys  the concept of taking care of the little ones.

Questions:

- what’s the more likely first usage year  of babysitter, given that the sources cited above offer quite different views.
- does  “sitter” refer to broody hens or are there other more plausible origins of the term?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81611/discussion-on-question-by-user070221-what-does-sitter-refer-to-in-babysitter).

Comment: What does 'napper' refer to in 'kidnapper'? Many similar questions can be asked.

Comment: @MalayTheDynamo - yes, that could be an interesting one. Why don’t you make a full detailed and researched question about it?

Comment: Compare German *gesitted* "civilized, well behaved", *Sitte* "manner, tradition", further *to settle*. If there's a similar relation as between *kidnapper*, Ger. *Nepper, neppen*, then it means *a nurse*, somebody to accommodate and calm the child.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'Sitters' of various sorts were much in the news in the early 1930s. Tree-sitters, flagpole sitters and house sitters all made appearances. For example, this concerning a long-staying house guest, from the [*Barnard Bulletin* (New York, New York) of 07 Nov 1930](https://www.newspapers.com/image/37829727/?terms=%22house%2Bsitter%22):

> As his host remarks, "I've heard of flag-pole sitters and tree sitters, but, by God, this fellow's a house sitter!"

Note that flag-pole sitting, tree sitting and, in this case, house sitting, did not connote care for or attention to, respectively, flag-poles, trees and houses, but rather were practiced as faddish and capricious tests or contests of endurance.

The term 'baby sitters', however, so far as I can discover, was coined by or to describe one arm of the "Hop Light Ladies" in 1933, as mentioned in other answers. The "Hop Light Ladies" were a group of female entrepreneurs who, "before the depression were writers, sculptors, painters, interior decorators and business women". Syndicated stories about these depression-era worthies were edited variously. One version states that a

> younger group [of the Hop Light Ladies], to be known as "Baby Sitters," will offer their services to supply reliable women at low cost to couples who wish to leave their youngsters in reliable hands at home while they have an evening out.
>
> [*The Tennessean* (Nashville, Tennessee), 25 May 1933.](https://www.newspapers.com/image/167850869/)

The phrasing of the article intimates (but only intimates) that the term was coined by the Hop Light Ladies to describe one of their many money-making endeavors.

'Baby-sitter' did not appear in a vacuum, of course. Influences on its development and adoption worth mentioning, other than the above-attested general prevalence in depression-era US news of 'sitters' of various sorts, include earlier use in the US of the slang term 'baby-herder', along with slang use of the noun 'sit' as a shortening of 'situation'.

The somewhat earlier 'baby-herder' and later 'baby-sitter' are in contrast to the now-historical and derogatory 'baby-farmer' (1867), one "who undertakes the charge of children for a fixed sum" (*OED*). 'Baby-sitter' may well have been deliberately coined with the idea of avoiding entrepreneurial association with the practice of 'baby-farming'.

Add to these influences that 'sit' (the verb) had long been used with appositive complements to denote "the position or occupation of a person" ([*OED*](http://oed.com/), **sit**, *v.*, **7c**, attested from around 825).

Of the 'baby-herders' and the noun 'sit' meaning "situation", the following evidence pertains.

The slang 'sit' meaning "situation" appeared first, in 1853. Originally, the term referred to type compositers:

> **sit,** *n.*<sup>2</sup>
>   ...
>   *slang* (orig. *Printing*).
>   = SITUATION *n.* 6b.
>   1853   ‘M. Twain’ in *Hannibal* (Missouri) *Jrnl.* 8 Sept. 2/1   I shall look out for a sit; for they say there is plenty of work to be had for *sober* compositors.
>
> [*OED*](http://oed.com/)

Use of the slang 'sit' is further attested in *OED* through 1914. Also, numerous 'Work Wanted' ads of the following general form appear in US newspapers throughout the late decades of the 1800s and the early decades of the 1900s:

[image: sit for baby]

(from the [*St. Louis Post-Dispatch*, Missouri, 20 Sep 1912](https://www.newspapers.com/image/138935489/?terms=%22sit%2Bwith%2Bbaby%22)).

The US slang 'baby herder' does not appear in *OED*. I found a scattering of appearances of the term in US newspapers from 1875 through 1947. The first, from 1875, makes the connection between 'sit' and 'baby herder':

> Many of the miners of the Salmon mountains are wintering in the Lembi valley, some of whom have received temporary "sits" as "baby herders", receiving therefor regular rations of substantial grub.
>
> [*The Independent-Record* (Helena, Montana), 16 Mar 1875](https://www.newspapers.com/image/39254025/?terms=%22sit%2Bwith%2Bbaby%22).

Further appearances (for example, in 1878, 1887, 1888, 1891, 1894) firmly establish that the intended meaning of 'baby herder' is 'baby sitter', and a 1947 appearance in an article listing some of the contents of *The American Thesarus of Slang* (Lester V. Berrey and Melvin Van den Burk) provides one definition:

> A nurse maid is a baby herder or kindergardener.
>
> [*The Winnipeg Tribune (Winnipeg, Manitoba, Canada), 23 Apr 1947](https://www.newspapers.com/image/37399634/?terms=%22baby%2Bherder%22).

---

### One Spurious 1914 Appearance of 'Baby-Sitting'

The 1914 first appearance date given unattested by [*Etymology Online*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/babysitter) may have been sponsored by an OCR error, as shown under **About this Book** ("Baby-sitting campaigns pliminary report..." at left) in [the Google scan of a 1914 US Government Printing Office monograph titled **Baby-Saving Campaigns**, produced by the US Department of Labor Children's Bureau](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt/search?q1=baby%20sitting;id=hvd.hl37kb;view=1up;seq=1;num=1;start=1;sz=10;page=search;orient=0).

Answer (score 8):

> [W]hat’s the more likely first usage year of babysitter...[?]

It's a longstanding issue on this forum that, no, *Etymology Online* isn't a very reliable source. It's essentially a Wikipedia of one and we'd be better off if Mr Harper published his sources to verify claims.

**The OED gives 1937**: [See [Mr Yargs's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/459998/171986) for a still earlier 1933 cite]

> 1937 C[harles] R[umford] Walker [*Amer*[*ican*] *City* [p.] 230](https://books.google.com/books?id=MAslAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22american+city%22+walker&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=baby+sitters):
>
> > There are two high-school girls in the neighborhood who hire out for twenty-five cents an evening as ‘baby sitters’ when the family wants to go to the movies.

That's presumably the same 1937 source mentioned by Ms Forman–Brunell in [Ubi Hatt's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/459864/171986).

Wikipedia labelled [this 1914 Japanese photo](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Babysitter_under_bamboo_tree_in_Japan_(1914_by_Elstner_Hilton).jpg) "Babysitter under Bamboo Tree in Japan" but [the Flickr source](https://www.flickr.com/photos/adavey/5078786422/) makes it clear that the original title was "Mother and Child" and the idea that it was a nanny is a later supposition.

Similarly, Google Books is full of hits for variations of babysitting before 1937 but upon inspection they all turn out to be misdated (e.g., [this *New Yorker* story](https://books.google.com/books?id=zCwdAQAAMAAJ) from the '50s) or bundled in a single file with earlier works (e.g., [these](https://books.google.com/books?id=2KmhfMJfxRcC&pg=RA2-PA48) [two](https://books.google.com/books?id=QJ1GAQAAIAAJ&pg=RA1-PA132) gov't reports).

> [D]oes “sitter” refer to broody hens or are there other more plausible origins of the term?

In the first decades of the 20th century, legitimate Google Books results for the term *sitter* invariably refer to people sitting (on church pews or in other contexts), to artists' models (i.e., *someone who sits for a picture*), or to automatic writers or other seance participants apart from the medium herself (a clever calque from the original French, where a *séance* was literally *a sitting*). The OED gives the first use of *sitter* as a clipped form of *babysitter* [as 1943](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/180507).

There's no use of "sitting on" the baby as though it were a well-tended egg in the 20th *or* 19th century.

The 1937 source does describe a far more likely derivation: those unskilled girls were hiring themselves out for an entire evening for what a regular cleaning lady or nanny would charge for a single hour of work. In other words, they weren't skilled nannies or maids offering a full range of services; **they literally only *sat with* the baby** and kept an eye on it to make sure nothing went too wrong. With the rise of the middle class and decline of domestic servants, such services by such unskilled teens eventually became the norm and a standard job description.

[The OED claims to offer usage of 'sitter by' with the sense 'babysitter'](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/180507) back to the 16th century, but the citations are actually describing lackeys and viceroys rather than caretakers of infants.

Answer (score 6):

`What’s the more likely first usage year of babysitter, given that the sources cited above offer quite different views.`

## Updated part1

►After datamining information from the archives of Library Of Congress with parameter: 1920-1950 & "baby sitter", I was able to find this oldest entry ***May 25, 1933*** (printed nearly 3 months prior than that cited by [Sven Yargs](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/459998/273365)).
*It wasn't an easy task. The search engine of archive mistook "baby sitter" as "baby sister", urgh!.*

► 1.  [Evening star. [volume], May 25, 1933, Page B-11, Image 27](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83045462/1933-05-25/ed-1/seq-27/#date1=1930&index=0&rows=20&words=baby+sitters&searchType=basic&sequence=0&state=&date2=1933&proxtext=%22baby+sitters%22&y=0&x=0&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1) &

Image.
[image]

Other citations are,

2. [Sunday Star Date Sept 22, **1946**](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn78002169/1946-09-22/ed-1/seq-19.pdf)
3. [The Wilmington morning star., July 19, **1946**, Page 6, Image 6](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn78002169/1946-07-19/ed-1/seq-6/#date1=1789&sort=date&rows=20&words=baby-sitter&searchType=basic&sequence=0&index=3&state=&date2=1963&proxtext=%22babysitter%22&y=4&x=20&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1)
4. [The Sunday Star, Washington, D.C., October 24, 1948](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83045462/1948-10-24/ed-1/seq-154.pdf)

►Also, there is an entire book written on the subject: [Babysitter: An American History](https://academic.oup.com/jah/article-abstract/97/1/231/719202?redirectedFrom=fulltext) by Miriam Forman-Brunell (ISBN 978-0-8147-2759-1). In which, author indicates following:

> "Baby-sitting emerged during the **1920s** with the decline of other child care providers and the rise of an expanded youth culture. The term “baby-sitter,” which replaced “neighborhood helper” or “child minder,” first appeared in print in 1937."

► But with the evidence we have from Library of Congress, we are certain that it first appeared in print prior to 1937 in *Evening star* dated May 25, 1933 (as of now).

**Excerpts from the book [Babysitter: An American History By Miriam Forman-Brunell](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=KnaKW5zvkUgC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)**

[image]1

[image]2

---

`Does “sitter” refer to broody hens or are there other more plausible origins of the term?`

## part2

►Well, according to [GNU Collaborative International Dictionary of English](http://gcide.gnu.org.ua/?q=sitter&define=Define&strategy=.) the other meaning of  sitter as "A bird that sits or incubates" was registered in the year 1913 in Merriam Webster. Few years earlier than that of babysitter.

[image]

►But interestingly there is no mention of this meaning on the online version of Merriam Webster. Online OED version defines [sitter](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sitter)**<sub>1.1</sub>** as "A sitting hen".

►Source: [freethesaurus.com](http://www.memidex.com/sitters+hen#etymology)
[image]

►Here, how sitter conceived the meaning of someone who tends/cares/nurse is a subject of etymological investigation.

► Sitter in [Tree sitter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_sitting), [house sitter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_sitter), [pet sitter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pet_sitting) also has a connotation of someone who tend/care/nurse/protect.

►But establishing links between **sitter** and *someone who* **tends/cares/nurse/protects** is entirely a different proposition. Until then the "sitter" in the "baby-sitter" will be shrouded in the mystery.

►Further reading:

1. [History of Babysitting](https://bebusinessed.com/history/history-of-babysitting/)
2. [Adventures in Feministory: The History of the Babysitter](https://www.bitchmedia.org/post/adventures-in-feministory-the-history-of-the-babysitter)
3. [Babysitter: An American History By Miriam Forman-Brunell](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=KnaKW5zvkUgC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: +1 for citing the book by Miriam Forman-Brunell. Is there any suggestion in that book about the usage of “sit/sitter”?

Comment: @user070221 :) I haven't gone through entire book!

Comment: @user070221 it is not brooding hen, but 2nd meaning of sitter which is mysterious :)

Comment: Yes, that is what my question is about.

Answer (score 6):

Here are the earliest relevant occurrences of several terms related to *babysitter* that Elephind newspaper database searches find. The first and third instances below appear to be slightly older than the first occurrences noted by the OED (as user070221 reports them in the question above).

For ***babysitter***: From "[Women's Job Plan: Banishing Care with Colour](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/24893306?searchTerm=%22baby+sitters%22)," in the *[Hobart, Tasmania] Mercury* (August 14, 1933), revised from an article published in the *New York Times*:

> Taking their title ["Hop Light Ladies"] from an old Virginian song, the women have chosen gay uniforms as they proceed to canvass New York householders for custom in various ways. Some of them, working in pairs, are prepared to go from house to house offering to paint chairs and flower boxes or otherwise brighten homes until these are as gay as themselves. These have chosen rose-coloured costumes. Others, selling plants, wear green dresses, while a third group, in bright blue, have obtained police per mission to erect bookstalls In the big City Square with gaily painted stands. Others, known as "**baby sitters**," offer to take care of the children of married couples wishing to spend an evening at the cinema.

One might speculate that babysitting as a profession may have emerged in the depths of the Great Depression, but this article provides only circumstantial evidence in support of that possibility.

For ***babysitting***: From Jean Seligman, "[YWCA Welcomes Freshmen Women at Dessert Dinner](http://idnc.library.illinois.edu/cgi-bin/illinois?a=d&d=DIL19440303.2.45&txq=%22baby+sitting%22)" in the *[Urbana-Champaign, Illinois] Daily Illini* (March 3, 1944):

> Marjorie Colton, head of the child care project, explained the proposed child care discussion groups. This project will also include visiting nurseries, **baby sitting**, and making toys.

For ***babysit***: From "[Bundling in Brookline](https://newspaperarchives.vassar.edu/cgi-bin/vassar?a=d&d=vq19441115-01.2.13&txq=%2522baby+sit%2522)," in *Vassar Quarterly* (November 15, 1944):

> Came the cold weather and the engineer next door and market boy across the street shovelled the walks, the Catholic priest over the way and policeman ’round the corner offered to do furnaces, the drugstore “cowboys” carried ash cans (just once), and the detective’s wife at the corner and school teacher opposite offered to “**baby sit**,” and the former sent in hot biscuits via young son (who seemed to have sampled them en route; he arrived still chewing and said they were awfully good).

And finally, the earliest instance I could find of someone joking that ***babysitting*** means sitting on a baby appears in [this headline](http://idnc.library.illinois.edu/cgi-bin/illinois?a=d&d=AUE19461108.2.17&txq=%22babysitting%22) from the *[Washington, D.C.] American Eagle* (November 8, 1946):

> **How To Meet A Difficult Situation Gracefully ; Or, When Babysitting Sit On The Baby**

Comment: @user070221: I didn't research the reasoning behind the word choice—and I don't mean for my posted answer to be taken as an attempt at a complete answer to your posted question(s). However, I imagine that the word choice arose from the practice of "sitting with" various people in need of special care—infants, patients convalescing from illness, the very old. That is, I expect that _sitter_ preceded _baby sitter_ by a considerable number of years, and that the latter term caught on as a way of describing a particular category of sitter. But this is simply speculation on my part.

Comment: Any idea where etymonline got the 1914 reference? Bravo for finding a 1933 citation.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I have no idea what Etymonline found—but a couple of things make me very doubtful that it is a valid date. First, when a term is very new and at all likely to be misunderstood, writers tend to put it in quotation marks, as happens with both the 1933 "baby sitters" instance and the 1944 "baby sit" instance that I note above. But when the term becomes familiar, the quotation marks disappear. So we have evidence that newspapers considered "baby sitters" in 1933 and "baby sit" in 1944 odd enough to require quotation marks. ...

Comment: ... Second, when a new term catches on, it is highly unusual for there to be a 20-year gap between the first recorded instance in the second—which (at the moment) is the gap we're dealing with between the 1914 citation and the 1933 instance. When the space is that large and the first occurrence is authenticated, I wonder whether the first instance might not be merely coincidental; more often, however, the earlier cited instance turns out to be invalid for one reason or another.

Comment: There is the 1913 M-W entry for "sitter" cited by @ubi hatt, which suggests that the term was in use long before it earned its place in the dictionary, and from sitter to babysitter the leap is not long.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Yes, that's the route that I think _babysitter_ took to enter the English language—and it may have happened in 1914, as Etymonline says. But I'm having no success replicating Etymonline's finding.

Comment: Maybe it started off as child-sitting or infant-sitter or sibling sitter (older kids told to look after their younger siblings) Who knows?

Comment: Ha! 1906 [So I hold that the photographer's relation to his child sitter should not be a too exciting or absorbing affair.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22child+sitter%22&num=20&tbm=bks&ei=DwJyW9KJMIfvvATMmZTYAw&start=20&sa=N&biw=1309&bih=619&dpr=1.1) different meaning but we're getting close.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: There are a number of instances of "baby sitter"—in the sense of baby sitting for a photograph—from the 1890s, especially in Australia. See the [third through tenth matches in this first page of Elephind results for "baby sitters"](https://elephind.com/?a=q&hs=1&r=1&results=1&txq=%22baby+sitters%22&txf=txINtxCO&o=10&dafyq=&dafmq=&dafdq=&datyq=&datmq=&datdq=&puqname=Search+all+titles...&puq=&lcq=&csq=&e=-------en-10--1-byDA-txt-txINtxCO-%22baby+sitter%22---------). I don't think they are related to the emergence of the child-care term, however.

Comment: I doubt Etym Online on principle but it is worth noting that the 1933 and 1937 are as far apart as Tasmania and Minnesota. It does speak to fairly widespread informal use or a phrasing tendency (along the lines of _we don't need a maid, just someone to sit with the baby some evenings each month_) that was able to be spontaneously reformatted multiple times in different environments.

Comment: You also sit with people in a ***sitting room***; attested in British and American English. So, it makes sense to say baby sit. Formerly, tending children. Also, in BrE: child minders.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, the *OED* clearly attributes the earliest of the "sitting" senses to "dog sitting."

> Earliest in the mid 20th cent. in *dog sitter* **n.** at *dog* **n.1** Compounds **3a.**

The earliest such date for dogs is still **1942**, well after the finding in Sven Yargs's answer.

> Never hire a boy for a **dog sitter** if you don't want a case of alienation of affections!

- **1942**   *Sunday News & Tribune* (Jefferson City, Missouri) 2 Oct. (Cartoon section) 4/3

To that end, if we're in search of an early **generic sitter** of sorts, we might search for a use of "sitter" pertaining to "one who cares for dogs."

Here's a good example:

> "Her portrayals are not simply 'dog' ", Edgar Selwyn wrote in "Modern Painters" [was not able to find a copy of this book], nor are they merely significant of the particular breed portrayed, but they are magical presentments of the character and personality of the **dog *sitter***.  To look at any one of the canvases or plates by Diana Thorne wherein the dog is subject is to say not simply "This is adequate "dog"' (the most complimentary compliment one can make with trith in respect to her contemporaries), but to exclaim--even as in the case of Sargent 'This is uncanny and masterly unveiling of the peculiar character of the **sitter** whose identity is forever established in imperishable memory."

- [**1930** *Lansing State Journal* (Lansing, Michigan) 11 Dec. 19/5](https://www.newspapers.com/image/204904400/?terms=%22dog%2Bsitter%22) (paywall)

This clipping uses the term "dog sitter" to refer to someone who cares for a dog and keeps them "sitting" while being painted.  It stands to reason that this sense of the word could likely have been what was extended to refer to "sitters" as caretakers in general and eventually "babysitter."

Comment: Your interesting answer appears to support the Wikipedia statement cited in my question : ”*The use of the word "sit" to refer to a person tending to a child is recorded from 1800*.” of which I couldn't find any evidence.

Comment: compound words like pet sitter, house sitter, etc. were derived from baby-sitter.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the answer is somewhat simpler: the origin of "to babysit" rests on the meaning of "to sit" and the meaning required is just over 1,000 years old in English and a evolution of a common use of "to sit.

> OED:
>
> **4.a. To occupy a seat** in the capacity of a judge or **with some administrative function.**
>
> c1000   Ælfric Exodus xviii. 13   Þig oðre dæȥe sæt Moises, þæt he wolde deman þam folce. [then the following day Moses sat in order to judge the people - my translation]
>
> 1896   Law Times Rep. 73 690/1   The summons was heard by the
> registrar, sitting as Deputy Chancellor.

In the former for example "Judgement sitting" would describe the action of the Moses.

In the latter for example "deputy Chancellor sitting" would describe the action of the registrar.

We may broaden this to any occupation with a responsibility.

Comment: You confuse *post ante quem* and *x years old*. You aren't really suggesting that Aelfric coined the term. Nor do you have any material evidence of the "evolution of the common sense"--except common sense, which is debatable. *sit* ~ *set* is highly polysemous to begin with: German has *Gesetz* "law", *Satzung* "s'tatute", *Satz* "sentence", *einsitzen* "(to be in) arrest", *einsetzen* "bail, support; inherit to s/b" and indeed *Sitzung* "sitting""; English has the legal *consideration* from Latin, which by your common sense derives from *sitting with*--which I have argued once, too

Comment: I suggest that all "sitting" in this formal sense is sitting "for something or for some purpose" - a dative. Here, the sitting is "for the baby". ++*Gesetz* has a nuance of "that which has been/is sat/set down" https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Gesetz#herkunft, or put firmly in place". To this extent, a millennium of use seems reasonable.

Comment: No, no, no, no. Why not from *sighting*, e.g., cp. *hearing*. The sitting for the baby doesn't make sense, the verb isn't transitive--that would be set--and it just doesn't sit well with me. *Gesetz* is, well yes ... I sed as much, but it's a pitfall to assume that any and all *ge-* would be an instance of the sofar reasonably uncertain prefix, when it could in fact reflect \*g'h-, rather than a Verner's Law'ed \*k'; likewise it's just tooo simple to see a primitive word and think *that must be it, they were after all very poor primitive people, who couldn't afford to stand!* ...

Comment: *The sitting for the baby doesn't make sense, the verb isn't transitive* It does not need to be it has no direct object... The baby is not "sat". You sit for the benefit of the baby

Comment: ... because there's no sustainable notion of primacy in semantics without circular definitions or linguistic relativism; there's no convincing prototype theory I don't think, and the school of (whatsitcalled, fundamental types?) is rather arbitrary. Further, it's unclear whether Jackendoff's natural metaphors are meant to be universal, or as a genre, and effectively to old to be tractable. It's difficult to give an appropriate critique of this bias in under 100 words. Please excuse me, I hope you know what I mean. In a quip, if I were to *sit* in the *stand*, I can only lose.

Comment: "It does not need to be" In my grammar it has to, if you want to use it without preposition. Clearly *Baby* is the direct object of *Sitter* in *baby-sitter*. See my allusions to *by-*, Ger. *bei-* up-thread for a tentative solution. More over, "sitting for" is not a idiomatic collocation, and reaching for unidiomatic explanations rather calls into doubt the strength of the argument, actually falsifying the appropriate preposition if I am correct, but I shouldn't rest on the assumption. *for* works as conjunction, i.e. *because*. I sit because the baby? That's not unheared but it's a bit ...

Comment: *More over, "sitting for" is not a idiomatic collocation,* Really? 1. "He sat for his portrait" - 2. "The portrait sitter was a young woman."

Comment: *He sat [because/in front] the portrait* (what would be *stand model* in German) does not have any relevance, nor e.g. *he sat five years for criminal negligence*. "For" can mean a myriad of relations, *in favor of, in stead of, in consequence of* etc. But *to sit for* is otherwise not a standing collocation, point in case, you don't *baby-sit for*. So your wording explains very little, requiring to accept *to sit* in that sense without the preposition to begin with. And then, it must be the nicest judge in the world, who sits *for* a criminal.